# Wordpress Civicrm -Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined for contribution page

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, issues, javascript, error-page

WordPress -  5.4.4 ,
CiviCRM -  2.62 ,
Theme Avada

Using shortcode added contribution to page but in console, we are getting error **Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined** so the page is not loading fully and payment option -  PayPal and credit card not displaying how we can fix this issue.

Also when we logged-in as admin there is no error in console and payment option showing properly

thanx

please check -
[image]

Comment: Are there any PHP errors being logged? CiviCRM might be serving a file that isn't Javascript if there are.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing this problem (CiviCRM 5.3.0, WP 5.6.1, Avada 7.2.1).

The CiviCRM-Javascript-Resources are not loaded at all.

**Disabling the Fusion Builder** (so working with the regular WP editor) for the page where the CiviCRM-shortcode is inserted **gets the resources loaded and the payment form working**.

We're still facing Avada layouts issues on the next page though. But at least registration and payment work now.